# Entity Framework 6 saving wrong decimal number

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I already solved this problem, but I don't understand why this is happening. I would love a more detailed explanation.

For context, I have this class:

```
public class Test : Entity<Test>
{
    public decimal DecimalProp { get; private set; }
}
```

And the EF mapping/config is like this:

```
public class TestConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Test> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Tests");            

        builder
            .Property(t => t.DecimalProp)
            .HasDefaultValue(-1)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(4,1)")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

When I add via EF a new Test with DecimalProp = 0, in SQL it saves as -1, but when I add with another number, like 5, it saves correctly.

I solved the problem using `ValueGeneratedNever` on the mapping class:

```
public class TestConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Test> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Tests");            

        builder
            .Property(t => t.DecimalProp)
            .HasColumnType("decimal(4,1)")
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasDefaultValue(-1)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

My colleagues think that since 0 is the default value for C#'s decimal, EF thinks it should use the default value on SQL which is now -1, but for me it doesn't feel right, since 0 could be a valid value.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The question would be: Why the EF is saving 0 as -1 before I solved with the ValueGeneratedNever.

Comment: My guess would be the logic is the same as with generating primary keys described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#dc)

Comment: @FelipeAlves -- you don't give most of the code -- so we can't see where you are using this, but it is clear -- the first one is using the default value of -1 and the 2nd one is not.  Do you actually set the first one to 0?  Show us the code -- looks like you had a bug testing the first one to me.

Comment: You want to use `.HasDefaultValueSql(-1)` not `HasDefaultValue(-1)` /w `ValueGeneratedNever()` to ensure EF doesn't start ignoring defaults for non-nullable types.

Comment: @Hogan I didn't add the actual code because is just a basic create function for EF (add and save changes). Both saves a new Test(0), but the first one results a -1 and the second results a 0

Comment: @StevePy yeah,  it makes sense, I didn't know EF ignored default C# values , this is the first time this happens so never thought it was a thing

Comment: Yes my point is the bug is clearly in the code you don't show (sounds like you had a non-nullable type set to 0 which was coveted to null.   Can't be sure without seeing the code that you did not provide.  As I said.